# How to select a cell relative to a button with a macro?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, macros

I am trying to create a macro in Excel which I can assign to a number of buttons (one in each row), each of which will operate on the data in the row in which the button is located.

Is it possible to do this, or do I have to create individual macros for each row and assign the appropriate one to the button in that row?

Comment: If the buttons have an address, you can reference that address (or target) in the macro. What have you tried already? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 0):

On the developper tab where the "record a macro" button is situated, you'll find an option to use relative reference.

It exactly does what you're looking for.

[image]